# Create and place JLabels on JPanel with a loop

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I'm new to swing and I've been trying some new things. I'd like to create and place JLabels on a JPanel, but as many as I want, using a loop. I'm trying to make a snake game, btw.

```
/*Up here I set the number of parts (JLabels) I want and instantiate my ArrayList 
to store them later.*/

snakeBodyParts = 3;
snakeBody = new ArrayList<>();


/*This is the part I'm struggling with. First, bodyPartIndex is going to go from 0 
to my desired number of parts. On each time it's going to store an int for the X position 
of the JLabel and an int for the Y position. That way I'm going to get
JLabels on a horizontal line, each time an unit farther away.*/

    for (int bodyPartIndex = 0; bodyPartIndex < snakeBodyParts; bodyPartIndex++) {
        snakePositionsX[bodyPartIndex] = 50 - (bodyPartIndex * UNIT_SIZE);
        snakePositionsY[bodyPartIndex] = 50;


/*Then, I add a JLabel to my list, and get it back to my "bodyPart" JLabel.*/
        snakeBody.add(new JLabel());
        bodyPart = snakeBody.get(bodyPartIndex);


/*Here I set the location on my "bodyPart" JLabel, using the coordinates I created before,
and set its icon (it's out of the loop)*/
        bodyPart.setLocation(snakePositionsX[bodyPartIndex], snakePositionsY[bodyPartIndex]);
        bodyPart.setIcon(imgIconBodyPart);

/*And finally I replace the old bodyPart with the recently modified one, I then add it to my JPanel (this.add) */
        snakeBody.set(bodyPartIndex, bodyPart);
        this.add(bodyPart, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(snakePositionsX[bodyPartIndex], snakePositionsY[bodyPartIndex], UNIT_SIZE, UNIT_SIZE));

    }
```

I'm pretty sure I've done a lot of things wrong, I'm still trying to understand what I'm doing, but the end result is a blank screen, can anyone help me? I really need to know how to do this.

Comment: *"..create and place JLabels on a JPanel, .. I'm trying to make a snake game.."*  My advice here would be to scrap all the components and simply draw the images or text directly to a custom painted panel, or a single 'canvas' image displayed in a (single) label.

Comment: *the end result is a blank screen*. So you want help with fixing a problem we can't even see, nor is there any relevant code to look at. Post the relevant code.